# Start Vim as my user with root privileges

Tags: permissions, users, root

I have my custom Vim files in `~/.vim` and settings in `~/.vimrc`. However, sometimes I have to edit some files in `/etc` and such.
If I start Vim like this:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/rc.conf
```

I lose my config since Vim uses its default one. So: how can I run Vim with root privileges to edit files without losing my user's settings (which are in my home directory)?
I have tried:

```
$ su username -c "vim /usr/lib/python2.7/setuptools/dist.py"
```

but Bash gives me `Permission denied`. However, the above command works for example for: `/etc/acpi/handler.sh`. Why is that?

Note: *username* is not root.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of `sudo vim /etc/rc.conf` use `sudoedit /etc/rc.conf` or `sudo -e /etc/rc.conf`. You may need to set the EDITOR environment variable to vim. This will run vim itself as the normal user, using your normal configuration, on a copy of the file which it will copy back when you exit.

Comment: Nice solution! I'll check this out as well.

Comment: I tried `sudoedit /etc/rc.conf` and `sudo -e /etc/rc.conf` and it opens vim, but my ~/.vimrc doesn't get loaded. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @apparat Try `export EDITOR=vim` first - it may be trying to run `vi`, which I don't know if it loads vimrc even when it is vim.

Comment: Well, I think this is the best answer. Thank you both.

Comment: @Random832 `export EDITOR=vim` worked. I thought vi isn't installed on my system and is only a symlink to vim. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-u` to tell vim which rc file to load.  e.g.

`sudo vim -u ~user/.vimrc /etc/rc.conf`

if typing that every time you need to do it is tedious, make an alias:

`alias sudovim='sudo vim -u ~user/.vimrc'`

Note that `vim -u` may cause plugins or called rc files to fail if they load other files relative to $HOME - $HOME is now root's home dir, not the user's.  This can be solved with e.g. symlinks in root's home dir or by hard-coding absolute paths.

Comment: That's great, thank you. I solved like this: `alias svim="HOME=/home/user && sudo vim -u $HOME/.vimrc"`.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo vim -S /home/user/.vimrc /etc/rc.conf`

This is equivalent to:

`sudo vim /etc/rc.conf` + `:source /home/user/.vimrc`

and can be aliased as well:

`alias svim='sudo vim -S /home/user/.vimrc'`